# Android: Search through a custom list

Tags: android, search, android-listview

Is there a way where I can search through a list with custom Class in it? Also I would like to add voice search if possible.

The sounds class

```
            private int _id;
        private String _productname;
       private String _extra;
        private int _image;

        public SoundListed() {

        }

        public SoundListed(int id, String productname, String extra, int image) {
            this._id = id;
            this._productname = productname;
            this._extra = extra;
            this._image=image;
        }

        public SoundListed( String productname, String extra, int image) {
            this._productname = productname;
            this._extra = extra;
            this._image=image;
        }
        public void setID(int id) {
            this._id = id;
        }

        public int getID() {
            return this._id;
        }
        public int getImage(){return this._image;}

        public void setProductName(String productname) {
            this._productname = productname;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return this._productname;
        }

        public void setExtra(String extra) {
            this._extra = extra;
        }

        public String getExtra() {
            return this._extra;
        }


And the adapter:

    public class soundAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private List <SoundListed> listSounds;
    public soundAdapter(Context context, List<SoundListed> friends) {
        super(context, R.layout.customrow, friends);
        this.context=context;
        this.listSounds=friends;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.soundrow,null);
        }
        SoundListed s = listSounds.get(position);
        TextView soundName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameOfFile);
        TextView soundExtras = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.extraText);
        soundName.setText(s.getProductName());
        soundExtras.setText(s.getExtra());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Short explanation - This is sort of a soundboard and I wan to user to be able to search both with the soundExtras and the soundName (I am using the action bar search widget to search through the list)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First Filter the List<SoundedList> class based on search text and send it to Adapter on Text Change to repopulate List with new values

Comment: How? May you give me an example

Comment: @EnderNicky I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible

```
       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String search) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String search) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //if you use ArrayAdapter
           // MainActivity.this.soundadapter.getFilter().filter(search);    
            //custom adapter you need to add custom filter                
              MainActivity.this.soundadapter.filter(search);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

in your soundAdapter

```
private Context context;
private List <SoundListed> listSounds;
 //you need temp list of data for your feature use
private List <SoundListed> listSoundsTemp;

public soundAdapter(Context context, List<SoundListed> friends) {
    super(context, R.layout.customrow, friends);
    this.context=context;
    this.listSounds=friends;
    this.listSoundsTemp=friends;
}

void filter(String search)
{       
   if(search=="")
       listSounds = listSoundsTemp;
   else
   {
      List <String> listClone = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        for (SoundListed list: listSoundsTemp) {
            if(s.getProductName().matches("(?i)("+search+").*") || s.getExtra().matches("(?i)("+search+").*")){
               listClone.add(list);
           }
        }
      listSounds= listClone;
   }
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Should I override this in any way? or where should I call it?

Comment: Yes I know, but when I add it nothing changes, so should I override it or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText inputSearch;//your search box 
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                     adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);    
                     //Use your adapter object name instead adapter
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
        });
```

Comment: nope. This will not work. Check the answer to the question for more info